# Loop through DF, find values in one column that match list, add totals for each list value found and print

Tags: r, dataframe

1. I have a dataframe called df with variables AllCustomerName, and sum.of.FY.Total . The first column "AllCustomerName" has a list of all clients. I have a separate list that contains the names of the customers who I need information on. The code below is meant to loop through the dataframe column AllCustomerName, search for all values that equal my list values, and respectively add all values per each list observation.

   `y <- list("client 1", "client 2", "client 3")
       for ( i in y){
     if ( df$AllCustomerName == i ){
       sum(df$Sum.of.FY.Total)
     }
   }`

When I run the code I however get warnings saying  "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Thanks

Comment: So you're trying to code your own version of `merge`? Perhaps you could make a reproducible example? [There are great tips here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061). Either simulate data or share it with `dput()`.

Comment: Please consider removing your rstudio tag. R and rstudio are distinct pieces of software and your question is not related to rstudio.

Comment: Or maybe you want `aggregate(sum.of.FY.Total ~ AllCustomerName, FUN = sum, data = subset(df, AllCustomerName %in% y))`.

Comment: Why not just subset df where `df$AllCustomerName %in% y` then `group_by  AllCustomerName` and `summarise`

Comment: @Imo you are right. Not sure how/why rstudio was tagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[AllCustomerName %chin% unlist(y), .(Sum = sum(Sum.of.FY.Total)), 
                by = AllCustomerName]
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I didn't think about using this package. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. Did that a few minutes ago.

Comment: Quick question. Pardon if it sounds trivial. Keeping the same data.table syntax, is it possible to look for and sum all partial matches for the parent items in list "y". Only way I can think is to use the `pmatch()`  function, which works but with your solution isn't effective.

Comment: @Lyle Can you post as a new question with a reproducible example

Comment: I just did [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649749/how-to-search-dataframe-for-partial-matches-and-sum-separate-column-then-return) @akrun