# How to search dataframe for partial matches and sum separate column then return all matches with corresponding sums

Tags: r, dataframe

### This is a follow up to a previous question.

I have a dataframe called df2 with variables AllCustomerName, and sum.of.FY.Total . The first column "AllCustomerName" has a list of all clients. I have a separate list that contains the names of the customers who I need information on (NeedClientInfo). My code is meant to search the DF for all observations in "allcustomername" that partially or completely match the strings found in my NeedClientInfo list, and per each match, sum that clients numbers in the "sum.of.FY.Total" column. Ultimately I want to return the sums for each client and also the list of matching strings for each client.

---

## Main Dataframe

```
dput(df2)
structure(list(Transaction.ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 
74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 
90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 
105, 106, 107, 108), AllcustomerName = structure(c(44L, 8L, 40L, 
45L, 14L, 42L, 19L, 29L, 21L, 12L, 6L, 23L, 3L, 34L, 10L, 27L, 
25L, 36L, 38L, 54L, 1L, 53L, 17L, 51L, 47L, 32L, 57L, 43L, 7L, 
39L, 45L, 13L, 41L, 18L, 28L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 22L, 2L, 33L, 9L, 
26L, 24L, 35L, 37L, 54L, 4L, 52L, 15L, 49L, 46L, 30L, 55L, 43L, 
7L, 39L, 45L, 13L, 41L, 18L, 28L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 22L, 2L, 33L, 
9L, 26L, 24L, 35L, 37L, 54L, 4L, 52L, 15L, 49L, 46L, 30L, 55L, 
43L, 7L, 39L, 45L, 13L, 41L, 18L, 28L, 20L, 11L, 5L, 22L, 2L, 
33L, 9L, 26L, 24L, 35L, 37L, 54L, 4L, 52L, 16L, 50L, 48L, 31L, 
56L), .Label = c("Bank of America ( BOA ) Op", "BMW", "BMW Motorsport", 
"BOA", "Chevy", "Chevy Inc.", "Coca Cola", "Coca Cola Ltd.", 
"Ferrari", "Ferrari Marketing", "Ford", "Ford Holdings", "Gap", 
"Gap llc.", "Giant", "Giant Corp", "Giant Foodstores", "Gucci", 
"Gucci Partners", "Hermes", "Hermes Marketing", "Honda", "Honda Parnters", 
"John Deere", "John Deere Operations", "Lamborghini", "Lamborghini Accounting", 
"Louis Vuittons", "Louis Vuittons HR", "McDonalds", "McDonalds Corp", 
"McDonalds UK", "Mercedes Benz", "Mercedes Benz inc.", "NBA", 
"NBA Analysis", "NFA ", "NFA Recruitment", "Nike", "Nike Finance", 
"North Face", "North Face LTD.", "Pepsi", "Pepsi Holdings", "Ralph Lauren", 
"Range Rover", "Range Rover Ad", "Range Rover Corp", "Safeway", 
"Safeway Corp", "Safeway Holdings", "Suntrust", "Suntrust Bank", 
"VFC Corp", "Wendys", "Wendys 2", "Wendys SNG"), class = "factor"), 
    sum.of.FY.Total = c(4916487, 4663357, 909996, 4471305, 1720676, 
    7034137, 4017939, 4524008, 5547914, 1980483, 1203141, 132121, 
    3594657, 1598713, 2182312, 4779278, 6512046, 8136679, 5655455, 
    2159191, 9360006, 156573, 9140869, 7536559, 9130948, 4669661, 
    6194570, 4272497, 4550240, 3548889, 9750697, 2088667, 4534458, 
    5476184, 4883956, 6779033, 3579352, 1011840, 4310802, 2235088, 
    3643387, 757483, 6935256, 2990853, 53131, 5585040, 7877862, 
    3665289, 1367070, 8753575, 3524916, 5680361, 5069410, 4627819, 
    4653707, 9991615, 5618644, 5070332, 772305, 1207882, 491771, 
    9741735, 3865162, 4068133, 4462921, 9125132, 9212654, 4210293, 
    8604194, 2994089, 7387356, 3862073, 2008803, 9893430, 6231332, 
    2676382, 1596216, 6576172, 8960161, 8323238, 3122570, 4532453, 
    2713177, 661403, 9725618, 2986872, 5799460, 3136023, 6345920, 
    231895, 7786946, 2341224, 4352162, 2654683, 4706294, 8396018, 
    3144172, 2100856, 2828535, 6487379, 7779024, 8635949, 441559, 
    7928063, 3935233, 3902695, 6505559, 1194013)), .Names = c("Transaction.ID", 
"AllcustomerName", "sum.of.FY.Total"), row.names = c(NA, -108L
), class = "data.frame")
```

---

List of clients

```
dput(NeedClientInfo)
list("Pepsi", "Coca Cola", "Nike", "Ralph Lauren", "Gap", "North Face", 
    "Gucci", "Louis Vuittons", "Hermes", "Ford", "Chevy", "Honda", 
    "BMW", "Mercedes Benz", "Ferrari", "Lamborghini", "John Deere", 
    "NBA", "NFA ", "VFC Corp", "BOA", "Suntrust", "Giant", "Safeway", 
    "Range Rover", "McDonalds", "Wendys")
```

---

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[AllCustomerName %chin% unlist(NeedClientName), .(Sum = sum(Sum.of.FY.Total)), 
                by = AllCustomerName]
```

This is the latest iteration of the code for this problem. It however does not account for partial matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
l2 <- lapply(NeedClientInfo, function(i) grep(i, df2$AllcustomerName))
l3 <- lapply(l2, function(i) sum(df2$sum.of.FY.Total[i]))
names(l3) <- unlist(NeedClientInfo)
head(l3)
#$Pepsi
#[1] 18375144
#$`Coca Cola`
#[1] 21918389
#$Nike
#[1] 10738932
#$`Ralph Lauren`
#[1] 29017952
#$Gap
#[1] 7568520
#$`North Face`
#[1] 18575937
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. Otherwise I would have just done this through a SQL query, but I am trying to understand the R syntax better.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%like%` instead of `%chin%` in your data.table `i` select.  Should do partial matches.  Details on how `%like%` works [can be found in Data.Table Documentation on page 44](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf)
.